# Win32 API: capture window not working for all windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to capture some windows on windows 10.

But some windows are not working...

here is my code:

```
bool getWindowSize(unsigned int& width, unsigned int& height) const
{
    RECT rect;
    if (GetClientRect(m_hwnd, &rect))
    {
        width = rect.right - rect.left;
        height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void capture()
{
    unsigned int width = 0;
    unsigned int height = 0;
    getWindowSize(width, height);

    HDC deviceContext = GetDC(m_hwnd);
    HDC memoryDeviveContext = CreateCompatibleDC(deviceContext);
    HBITMAP bitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(deviceContext, width, height);
    SelectObject(memoryDeviveContext, bitmap);
    BitBlt(memoryDeviveContext, 0, 0, width, height, deviceContext, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
    bi.biSize = sizeof(bi);
    bi.biWidth = width;
    bi.biHeight = -static_cast<int>(height);
    bi.biPlanes = 1;
    bi.biBitCount = 32;
    bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 1;
    bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 2;
    bi.biClrUsed = 3;
    bi.biClrImportant = 4;

    BITMAPINFO MyBMInfo = { 0 };
    MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(MyBMInfo.bmiHeader);

    unsigned char* rawData = new unsigned char[4 * width * height];

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 4 * width * height; ++i)
    {
        rawData[i] = 0;
    }

    // Get the BITMAPINFO structure from the bitmap
    GetDIBits(memoryDeviveContext, bitmap, 0, height, &rawData[0], (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    //and here I'll work with "rawData"
    ...

    delete[] rawData;
    DeleteObject(bitmap);
    DeleteDC(memoryDeviveContext);
    ReleaseDC(m_hwnd, deviceContext);
}
```

e.g. A Window which I can not capture is windows calculator. Discord can capture it...
Some other windows work fine (e.g. Blender)

What am I doing wrong?

How can I fix this?

Comment: Use `SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT` to also capture layered windows.

Comment: This is not how you would capture a window. See [this blog post](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/09/16/new-ways-to-do-screen-capture/) to learn how to capture windows/screens.

Comment: The class of calculator is Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow. Calculator is not a simple window but uwp.